# Can you detect font from a remotely hosted iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, embed

Is there a way to make a remotely hosted iframe inherit/detect the parent font css treatment?

- Edit - no control over the parent, other than the embed code.

Comment: In general, nothing is inherited between iframes in different domains.

Comment: Communication is available using `postMessage()`, but it requires explicit cooperation between the JavaScript in the parent and child.

Comment: @Barmar - is there a working example anywhere that you know of? Something simple like p,span,a styles being read/passed and applied?

Comment: Working example? I said it can't be done.

Comment: `postMessage()` would require changes to the parent, which you said can't be done.

Comment: Sorry to be clear, when the embed code is generated I can include js (already doing this for iframeresizer, which uses postMessage).

Comment: So you're really asking how to get CSS using JS, which you can send using `postMessage`?